# How do I convert a series of mathematical constraints into a SAT or a SMT problem and get an answer?

Tags: sat-solvers

I have an arbitrary set of constraints. For example:

```
A, B, C and D are 8-bit integers.

A + B + C + D = 50
(A + B) = 25
(C + D) = 30
A < 10
```

I can convert this to a SAT problem that can be solved by picosat (I can't get minisat to compile on my Mac), or to a SMT problem that can be solved by [CVC4](http://cvc4.cs.stanford.edu/).  To do that I need to:

1. Map these equations into a Boolean circuit.
2. Apply Tseitin's transformation to the circuit and convert it into DIMACS format.

My questions:

1. What tools do I use to do the conversion to the circuit?
2. What are the file formats for circuits and which ones are commonly used?
3. What tools do I use to transform the circuit to DIMACS format?

Comment: I think programming input for a specific piece of software is offtopic here. Community votes, please! And: would this fit better on [SO] or [scicomp.SE]?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30790 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12087

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting (math) problems to SAT instances](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/converting-math-problems-to-sat-instances)

Comment: IIt's close to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/converting-math-problems-to-sat-instances and I had read that question before posting. That question is theory-based, but does not ask for or offer practical answers.

Comment: We'd prefer that you ask only one question per post.  Asking about the file formats for a particular tool seems off-topic here (perhaps Stack Overflow might accept it; I don't know).  Asking for software recommendations or us to recommend a tool is questionable; I'm not sure that is within the scope of this site.

Comment: Okay; I can migrate this to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org), you could just write a constraint programming model:

```
set of int: I8 = 0..255;

var I8: A;
var I8: B;
var I8: C;
var I8: D;

constraint A + B + C + D == 50;

constraint (A + B) = 25;

constraint (C + D) = 30;

constraint A < 10;

solve satisfy;
```

The example constraints cannot be satisfied, because of `25 + 30 > 50`.

---

The Python interface of [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) would allow the following:

```
from z3 import *
A, B, C, D = Ints('A B C D')
s = Solver()
s.add(A >= 0, A < 256)
s.add(B >= 0, B < 256)
s.add(C >= 0, C < 256)
s.add(A+B+C+D == 50)
s.add((A+B) == 25)
s.add((C+D) == 30)
s.add(A < 10)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Answer (score 2):

### Conceptually

Build a circuit, then apply Tseitin's transform.

You'll need to express the addition and comparison operators as boolean logic.  There are standard ways to build a circuit for twos-complement addition and for twos-complement comparison.

Then, use Tseitin's transform to convert this to a SAT instance.

### In practice

Use a SAT front-end that will do this conversion for you.  Z3 will take care of this for you.  So will STP.  (The conversion is sometimes known as "bit-blasting".)

Comment: Thank you. I understand that building a circuit and applying Tseitin's transformation is the correct thing to do. I'm looking for software that goes from the mathematical formulas to the circuit and from the circuit to the DIMACS format. I'll clarify this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

So I have an answer. There's a program called [Sugar: a SAT-based Constraint Solver](http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/sugar/) which takes a series of constraints as S-expressions, converts the whole thing into a DIMACS file, runs the SAT solver, and then converts the results of the SAT solver back to the results of your constraitns.

Sugar was developed by Naoyuki Tamura to solve math puzzles like Sudoku puzzles. I found that it make it extremely simple to code complex constraints and run them.

For example, to find the square-root of 625, one could do this:

```
(int X 0 625)
(= (* X X) 625)
```

The first line says that X ranges from 0 to 625. The second line says that X*X is 625.

This may not be as simple and elegant as Z3, but it worked really well.